# Autosys: environment variables are not detected

Tags: autosys

jil file contains below profile location:

```
profile: /apps/properties/autosys_env.rc
```

Following environment variables are set in autosys_env.rc file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/apps/java/jdk1.7.0_51
export JAVA_HOME
ENV_MODE=DEV
export ENV_MODE
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

But, environment variables are not detected on executing jil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not working because I was creating autosys_env.rc file in windows and then copy it into unix machine using Winscp and Putty.

It seems windows has some characters that are not supported in unix.

So, it works after creating autosys_env.rc file in vi editor.